# My webcam is not working

Tags: webcam, camera

I can't turn on my camera on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS because no device found, I tríed to use Cheese, but it still doesn't work! How can I fix it?

Comment: Might be quite handy to know what camera this is? You could edit your question to specify the make/model, or run `lsusb` from a terminal & add the line that references your camera (or the whole output if unsure). Chances are you need a driver - but I can't tell you which one from the info provided!

Comment: I run lsusb -v and it appear like this http://paste.ubuntu.com/10677721/

Answer (score 0):

So we're looking at a Sony Viao laptop inbuilt camera; you need to be a member of "video" group to access it, or run cheese as root - a less good idea - and you may need to add a driver.

First, I would check that `/dev/video0` exists; if it does, you probably have a driver & need permissions; otherwise you need to install a driver.

I found a nice link to [driver details](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-927454.html) regarding the issues around this device - have a look at this, install the drivers it points to (but make sure you read it, don't just install the first thing!), & let us know how it goes?